# How do I add an extra horizontal line to a tabular{tables} object in R?

Tags: r, latex, tabular

I want to add an extra `\hline` to a complex table I created in an R sweave document using tabular(){tables}.

Using the Iris data as an example: I want to add an additional horizontal line underneath *Iris setosa*, spanning only the columns, not the row names. Currently, I've got this:

[image: Example of a table with multi-coloum header]

Code to generate the table:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
<<iristable, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='asis', message=FALSE>>=
library(Hmisc) ; library(tables)


tab.obj <- tabular( Species  ~ (Heading("Mean")*
                                  (Heading("")*mean*Sepal.Width +
                                   Heading("")*mean*Sepal.Length)) +
                               (Heading("Median")*
                                  (Heading("")*median*Sepal.Width +
                                   Heading("")*median*Sepal.Length)),
                    data=iris)

  nicetable<- booktabs() ## needs LaTex package \usepackage{booktabs}
  table_options(nicetable)
  table_options(titlerule="\\cmidrule(lr)")

latex(tab.obj)
@
\caption{This table is just an example.}
\end{center}
\label{tab:example_table}
\end{table}
```

I guess it must be possible, but I couldn't quite find out how.

Comment: *Disclaimer*: I don't want to go back to `xtable`, because I ran into trouble creating complex and nested tables there.

Answer (score 0):

looking into the function `tables:::latex.tabular` there is a way to compute the cline argument for titlerule,

```
   titlerules <- sprintf("%s%s{%d-%d}", titlerules, 
                        opts$titlerule, firstcol, firstcol + 
                          ncols - 1)
```

but not for the midrule. So you have to do it manually... Here is used

> table_options(midrule="\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}")

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
<<iristable, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='asis', message=FALSE>>=
library(Hmisc) ; library(tables)
tab.obj <- tabular( Species  ~ (Heading("Mean")*
                                  (Heading("")*mean*Sepal.Width +
                                   Heading("")*mean*Sepal.Length)) +
                               (Heading("Median")*
                                  (Heading("")*median*Sepal.Width +
                                   Heading("")*median*Sepal.Length)),
                    data=iris)

  nicetable<- booktabs() ## needs LaTex package \usepackage{booktabs}
  table_options(nicetable)
  table_options(titlerule="\\cmidrule(lr)")
  table_options(midrule="\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\\cmidrule(lr){4-5}")
latex(tab.obj)
@
\caption{This table is just an example.}
\end{center}
\label{tab:example_table}
\end{table}
```

[image: midrule_cline]